# Ajax CSRF Prevention without Cookies

Tags: php, ajax, cookies, csrf

Given `step1.php` with an authenticated user Id, calling `step2.php` with Ajax, I want to verify inside `step2.php` that it is legitimately called by `step1.php` and not by an attacker. I mainly want to protect against impersonating other users. I don't care if the same user calls me many times. And I need to do this without using cookies.

I'm trying to implement logic similar to the "Encrypted Token Pattern" mentioned [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Is the following secure enough, or am I overlooking something:

```
// step1.php
$userId = xxx;
$timeStamp = yyy;
$token = encrFunc($userId, $timeStamp); // encrFunc involves key known only to server
/* Generate JS code to call step2.php, posting userId and token */

// step2.php
$userId = $_POST['userId'];
$token = $_POST['token'];
$origUserId = decrFunc($token); // decrFunc involves key known only to server
if ($userId == $origUserId) { /* Continue normally */ }
else { /* I have been attacked! */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're extracting the UserId from the POST body. Your basic principal is correct in that you're validating the logged in user against the UserId claim in the token, however it's unusual to send the logged in UserId in the POST body. This should ideally be in the HTTP AUTH Header, although that's beside the point.